# Were there n number of entries made within x hours in last y hours

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, date-sub

Let's say there is a table with entries.
A user is not allowed to make more than 20 entries in 24 hours. If a user exceed this limit it will be banned for the next 24 hours.

```
id  user  datetime     
---|-----|-----------------
1  | 10  | 2021-06-01 23:01 
2  | 11  | 2021-06-01 23:04 
5  | 10  | 2021-06-01 23:31 
3  | 12  | 2021-06-01 23:59 
4  | 21  | 2021-06-02 00:01 
6  | 10  | 2021-06-02 00:09 
7  | 18  | 2021-06-02 01:15 
8  | 13  | 2021-06-02 03:02
```

I would like to check this (if possible) with one query.
As I imagine it, I should check if a user has made at least 20 entries within 24 hours in the last 48 hours. But how?

Comment: You can do it with the `LAG()` window function to count the number in the 24-hour period before each entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
select count(*), max(datetime)
from t
where user = ? and
      datetime >= now() - interval 24 hour;
```

When this hits your threshold you can ban the user.

Comment: Ban should last 24 hours from users last entry. Your solution requires an additional column where the starting/ending time of the ban should be stored. I would like to avoid that and just use only data from the given table.

Comment: @Goldie . . . No.  You would just add another column to the query.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I have overlooked something. You are absolutely right!